# Input text that starts with "#"

Tags: selenium, robotframework

How to insert text that starts with "### text and stuff" into argument of "Input Text" keyword from selenium2library using Robot Framework ?

Comment: what have you already tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: @drkthng unfortunately i didn't try anything because I don't know what to try. i just simply need: Input text - some xpath or css or whatever - text that starts with "#".

Comment: **`i just simply need`** is NOT going to help you at all. Try from your end and come back with your roadblock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must escape the first `#` with a backslash:

```
| | input text | id=some-element | \### text and stuff
```

This is mentioned in the robot framework user guide, in the section titled [Rules for parsing the data](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#rules-for-parsing-the-data).